# Re-render of child container ReactJS On state change in parent Container

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been searching and there are lot of similar questions but none solved my problem.

All the troubleshooting concludes as far as I think that if a connected component (aka container) to redux nests a child component also connected to same store. and when parents state gets updated it re-renders itself and its not connected child components but not nested connected component.

Just to be clear child connected component gets its data from parent but connected to create actions that in turn change the state of parent.

So my question is that assumption true? Or not ? and if yes what is the best way to deal with this. I know passing callbacks from parent would work. but hierarchy is in such a way that I have to pass callbacks through other components. i.e.

`containerA --> componentB --> containerC`

so when props of A updates through redux store it re renders, so does B too. but not C.

```
class HomePage extends Component{

renderActivities(){
    return _.map(this.props.activities, activity => {
        return <Activity activity={activity} key={activity.id}/>;
    });
}

render(){
    const {activities} = this.props;
    if(_.isEmpty(activities))
        return <div>Loading</div>;

    return <div>
              {this.renderActivities()}
        </div>
}
}

function mapStateToProps({ activities}) {
    return { activities};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchActivities})(HomePage);
```

ActivityItem.js

```
const Activity = ({activity}) => {
    const {user} = activity;
    return <div className="col-md-9"><MetaMovie movie={activity.movie}/></div>;
};

export default Activity;
```

MetaMovie.js

```
class MetaMovie extends Component {

render() {
    const {movie} = this.props;

    let action_btn = <button className="fa fa-plus" onClick={() => this.props.add(movie.id)}/>;
    if (movie.user_statuses !== null && movie.user_statuses.removed === false)
        action_btn = <button className="fa fa-minus" onClick={() => this.props.remove(movie.id)}/>;

    return action_btn;
    }
}

export default connect(null, {add, remove})(MetaMovie);
```

**EDIT**: Now I'm passing actions to `MetaMovie` as a callback and it works. It does not matter where action originates from. Right? So All I can think of it has something to do with `MetaMovie` now not being connected to redux store.

Comment: well, redux is passing the `props` to your child components, if no new `props` are passed then no render will happen. simple as that.

Comment: Not exactly child component is connected but does not take data from redux. Parent send data as prop in parent's render function. so when parent's render function is called it sets new data as props than why won't child updates.

Comment: Show some code, we can't guess.

Comment: @Sag1v I've added code. I did limit it to only necessary things to question.

Comment: seems like `MetaMovie` should rerender if `activity.movie` updates. If you console log the props from `MetaMovie`, do you see the new movie come through?

Comment: @JamesGentes I'm using redux dev tools and state changes i. e some properties on `activity.movie` change. but `MetaMovie` do not updates. I tried passing actions from `homepage` to` MetaMovie` through `Activity` using props and disconnected `MetaMovie` after that it works. So I think change in connected component won't update child connected component. Is that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: I suspect that you are mutating the movie object and not actually creating a new movie object. Connect's areOwnPropsEqual returns false because it only does a shallow comparison thus preventing a re-render for performance reasons.

Comment: @Zaptree If that be the case then why would it work if I'm just passing actions as callbacks to `MetaMovie` from `HomePage`. PS then it works fine.

Comment: @hamza-jutt that actually points to what I'm suggesting even more. After removing connect from MetaMovie you not longer have the performance optimizations that go with it so it will always re-render as long as the parent component renders. Maybe if you added the code from your reducer/action we would be able to see what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. You're setting the key for the Activity here:

`return <Activity activity={activity} key={activity.id}/>;`

But you're not actually using the key, which is what React needs to determine if it should re-render.

So in Activity you need to include the key:

```
const Activity = ({activity}) => {
    const {user} = activity;
    const {key} = this.props;
    return <div className="col-md-9" key={key}><MetaMovie movie={activity.movie}/></div>;
};
```

And if for some reason that still doesn't work, try forcing the re-render by changing key to `key={Math.random()}`.

Comment: First of all activity object re renders just not MetaMovie. And if that be the case then why would it work if actions are passed from parent to child component as callbacks. I would try force re render but that seems kinda hacky.

Comment: I think there's a problem with this: `const Activity = ({activity}) => ..` - if you console log `activity` there, what do you see?

Comment: i see an activity object.

Comment: and if you `const movie = activity.movie` and set `movie={movie}` and console log `movie` in MetaMovie, it never shows up, even though movie changes in the Activity component?

Comment: Yes. Redux toolbar also show diff but movie item never re renders.

Comment: I'm not sure you answered this question:  If you console log the props from MetaMovie, do you see the new movie come through? -- I'm not asking about what shows up in Redux.. I'm wondering if the render method may be getting called, but it's the actual component that's not changing. Sorry, this is a tricky one.

Comment: as I said at start Yes! it movie item's render not running.

Comment: could you add your reducer code or setup a jsfiddle or codepen with the issue?